# post error in angular 5 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Tags: angular, http, post

I am receiving this error when in angular 5 when I trying to consume a rest method (post):

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

This is the service:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ImageProvider{
    public url: string;
    
    constructor( public http: HttpClient){

        this.url='https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1&tags=?';
    }
    
    getImages(): Observable<any>{
                 
    
            let params = 'format=json&nojsoncallback=1&tags=?';     
                    
            let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
             
            return this.http.post(this.url+'productos', params, {headers: headers});
    }
}
```

and this is the component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ImageProvider} from '../../services/imageProvider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.css']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {
  public responseFlirck
  constructor(private _imageProvider: ImageProvider) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  
    this.getImagesFromFlirk();
  }


  getImagesFromFlirk(){

    this._imageProvider.getImages().subscribe(
      result => {  
        
          this.responseFlirck = result.data;
         
      },
      error => {
          console.log('Error in post');
          console.log(error);
      }
  );
  }

}
```

However in soap UI works fine:

[image]

Could someone please fix my code?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please google the error message, there are *so many duplicates*. This is **not** a problem with your Angular app, you need to enable CORS on the server. And please don't post screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jonrsharpe is right you need to enable CORS but if you need a very fast temporary solution ?

For example you need to give a presentation you can download this chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon